# Convergence in operator norm doesn't imply uniform convergence, examples?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am learning about functional analysis and the relation between operator norm convergence and uniform convergence is not so clear to me. I think that uniform convergence imply convergence in operator norm since if $\forall \epsilon \exists N$ such that if $n>N$ then $||T_n(x)-T(x)|| < \epsilon$ $\forall x$ then $\sup_{||x|| \le 1} ||T_n(x)-T(x)|| < \epsilon$ for $n>N$.

If we just have convergence in norm, it feels like we don't have necessarily uniform convergence but I cannot find counter-examples.

PS: there was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985178/operator-norm-convergence-does-not-imply-uniform-convergence) question without a clear answer (to me at least).

Answer (score 2):

The following should allow to find counterexamples - it also explains why the notion of uniform convergence doesn't come up in this context:

> > **Exercise.** Suppose $U$ and $V$ are normed vector spaces and $T_n:U\to V$ is linear for $n=1,2\dots$. If $T_n\to T$ uniformly then there exists $N$ such that $T_n=T$ for all $n>N$.

Hint: What does $||T_n(cx)-T(cx)||<\epsilon$ tell you about $||T_n(x)-T(x)||$?